# iOS ARC: OR operator on ManagedObject pointers

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm working with `NSManagedObjects` and I'd like to return either the tasks's budget or the task's category's budget.

However, the method gives the error:

```
Implicit conversion of int to Budget * is disallowed with ARC.
```

What's going on here?

```
@implementation Task

@dynamic category;
@dynamic budget;

- (Budget *)budgetOrCategoryBudget {
    return [self budget] || [[self category] budget];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` is an operator that takes two objects or primitives and returns `TRUE` if at least one of the values is non-nil (if an object) or non-zero (if a primitive) and `FALSE` otherwise.  In Objective-C BOOL is actually an int, where `FALSE` is `0` and `TRUE` is anything non-zero.  So you are actually returning a BOOL (represented by an int) where the compiler is expecting a `Budget *`.

If you want to actually return one of the two budgets, you must provide some other means of selecting between them.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
return [self budget] ? [self budget] : [[self category] budget];
```

Or, better

```
return ([self budget] != nil) ? [self budget] : [[self category] budget];
```

(Assuming that your intent is to return `[self budget]` if it exists, otherwise `[[self category] budget]`.)

Comment: Clang also supports the syntax `[self budget] ?: [[self category] budget]` (where the omitted second term has the same value as the condition).

Answer (score 2):

Calling

`return anything || somethingElse`

will return a boolean, which a managed object class turns into a 1 or 0. If you want to to return either [self budget] or [[self category] budget], write some sort of if statement:

```
if(condition){
   return [self budget];
}else{
   return [[self category] budget];
}
```